# kaltura admin console showing error because of public dns change amazon ec2

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, kaltura

I'm using the amazon ec2 to install my kaltura. I was installed it successfully and it was works fine. But after some time i have restarted my amazon ec2 instance so that the public DNS has changed. After that i have checked the kaltura. The start page is working fine but in the admin console it is showing

**An error occurred
Application error**

and i think it is because of publixc DNS change in amazon EC2.I have searched in many kaltura forums they asked to check **searchd, my.cnf** file configuration and change the **hosts** file configuration. Still i could not get the solution for my problem. Can anyone explain me what are files includes the host name in kaltura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it works by changing the public dns in the following file and restarted the apache server

app/admin_console/configs/application.ini

app/configurations/apache/my_kaltura.conf

app/alpha/config/kConfLocal.php

app/batch/batch_config.ini

app/batch/batches/Mailer/emails_en.ini